# Send "MOTD" to Minecraft client from custom Netty server

Tags: java, netty, minecraft

I have a basic Netty server (From the tutorial) (http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html), and it recieves the requests from the client, but how would I go about sending a string to the client?

For example, on a normal Minecraft server, you specify the "MOTD" in the configuration file, and when a client pings it from the server list, it will display that string. I need to do the same thing, but from my server code.

Comment: Is this still going to be in minecraft, or is it going to use your server? What are the rendering capabilities of the client? What research and/or code have you tried already?

Comment: It's going to be my custom server code. It's just a normal vanilla Minecraft Client. After doing extensive research for the last half hour, I have the general idea of what needs to be done, I just have no clue how to implement it.

Comment: It it a Bukkit plugin?

Comment: No, it is an entirely separate project. I am using Netty to create an alternative to a Minecraft Server.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to send the MoTD to the client you will have to figure out what gets sent in terms of protocol and data.

For example in the most basic form the data sent could be 1 byte for action (display motd) and then variable length for a string.

If I had to find out how to send this I would go look at the [open-source bukkit repositories](https://github.com/Bukkit) or the [Minecraft Decompiled Code Repository](https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev) to find out the way to do it myself.

Update:
Upon looking at the code it seems that also Minecraft uses Netty, so this plays in your advantage in terms of understanding it. Unfortunately the code is unofficially decompiled and thus obfuscated.

Update 2:
I believe the class you should inspect is

> net.minecraft.server.PacketStatusOutServerInfo

and the data sent appears to be JSON generated by the ServerPing class.

You can also check out [Minecraft Protocol](http://wiki.vg/Main_Page) (specifically [Ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping)); a place where modders can find an explanation of protocol & encryption.

Comment: That's why I chose Netty, because I saw that's what it uses. I'll take a look at that class, thanks. I've been digging through the source the whole time, forgot to reply.

Comment: Don't forget to look at the Ping Protocol in the bottom of the answer! That will probably be the most helpful.

Comment: I'll look at it now. Thanks again. I'll let you know if I have issues.

Answer (score 1):

This handler shows the sending of the MOTD:

https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/c1627dc9cc7505581993eb0fa15597cb36e94244/net/minecraft/server/LegacyPingHandler.java

It just happens to be that the MOTD handling goes on line number 69: https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/c1627dc9cc7505581993eb0fa15597cb36e94244/net/minecraft/server/LegacyPingHandler.java/#L69

When the channel receives the ping packet, it encodes the response into a ByteBuf and writes it back out of the channel.

Note that there are a few decompilation errors on the file - ignore them and fix it.

Comment: I had tried that code, it did not function. I might have been missing something, but I did take it directly from some decompiled source.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I am this far:
[link](http://pastebin.com/FV0BpHqd)

But it does not send any data.

Here's the main Server class, too:
[link](http://pastebin.com/gxvGcQuL)

Comment: Remember to check the protocol serialization.